# Sending custom objects across portlets in liferay

Tags: liferay, classloader, portlet, liferay-6

I'm having serious issues trying to send share custom objects between portlets in liferay. I have a Hook Plugin, with a servlet filter, which loads an object of Type MyCustomClass and inserts it into the request object as a parameter.

When i try to read this object in a portlet's render() i get a ClassCastException, though i am casting the object to the same class.

I understand that liferay plugins have different contexts, and i already tried to change the classloader before loading the object in the bean and portlet like this:

```
ClassLoader portalcl = PortalClassLoaderUtil.getClassLoader();
ClassLoader currentcl = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(portalcl);

//do my stuff

Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(currentcl);
```

however, it did not solved the problem, and the only way i found to solve the problem is to serialize the object into a json string, and deserialize it whenever i need it.

Isn't this kinda lame ? Does anyone know a better solution ?

Regards, DS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like the main problem you're seeing is that two different class loaders are loading the class which techncally makes them different classes (which it seems like you've already determined).

I haven't used LifeRay much but this has been a problem I've seen on other platforms as well. We were using WebSphere and solved this problem by putting the common MyCustomClass into a shared library that was on the server classpath. This way the server will load the class and make it available to all applications on the server through the server's single classloader. If you let each application load the class then you'll keep seeing this exception.

Comment: Well, i guess you are right, that seems to be the most legit approach, but it complicates a little bit the deployment process for our sysadmins, as we're still in an early phase of development, and change those classes a lot. So we ended up using json to send the objects from one portlet to another, until we reach a more solid state, or until liferay fixes it. Thanks for your feedback !

Comment: This thread is a bit old, but we ended up by moving all beans to a jar and placing that jar in the tomcat's lib directory like you suggested.